# Определить, входят ли элементы одного множества в другое множество

Tags: c++, stl, set

Подскажите, как более красиво определить, что хотя бы один элемент одного множества `std::set<TYPE>` входит в другое множество `std::set<TYPE>`

конечно всегда можно решить в лоб, т.е. пройти по одному множеству и проверять каждый элемент до положительного результата на вхождение во второе множество, но есть ли более короткие решения "в одну строчку", причем по хорошему не волнует сколько таких элементов и какие они

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользоваться алгоритмом [`set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Он даст те элементы, которые входят в оба множества.